# How do I prevent WIX CAQuietExec from logging the command line?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

In order to prevent command windows from popping up during installation I am using the WIX built-in custom action CAQuietExec.

First I define the command line:

```
<CustomAction Id="A01" 
       Property="QtExecCmdLine" Value="&quot;MyExe.exe&quot; /password [PASSWORD]" />
```

NB: The PASSWORD property is defined as Hidden. This prevents the Windows installer from writing the property value to the log.

Then I call into the embedded WIX extension:

```
<CustomAction Id="A02" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" />
```

This works fine.

However, when I go to the temp folder and open up the MSI log I see the following entry:

> CAQuietExec:  "C:\Program
>   Files\MyExe.exe" /password INCLEARTEXT

I.e. the password is displayed in clear text and not hidden.

How do I prevent the CAQuietExec from logging the password in clear text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In src\ca\wcautil\qtexec.cpp is this line in the QuietExec function:

```
WcaLog(LOGMSG_VERBOSE, "%ls", wzCommand);
```

which logs the command line in verbose mode. There is no conditional to stop it from logging.

Answer (score 2):

Took a few googles and try the solution is to create the proproperty and assign Hidden="yes" before assign the value to the property. In your code above, you should create a new property QtExecCmdLine before assign value.

```
 <Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Hidden="yes"></Property>
```

Then

```
 <CustomAction Id="A01" Property="QtExecCmdLine" Value="&quot;MyExe.exe&quot; /password [PASSWORD]" />
```

Then

```
 <CustomAction Id="A02" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`CustomAction`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) tag has a `HideTarget` attribute that should keep the custom action data from being written to the log.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that - added it to all possible custom actions - and it doesn't work. The problem is the code in CAQuietExec is not adhering to this attribute or the Hidden attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to attack your password.  I could look at the MSI in ORCA.  I could run WMIC path win32_process while it's running and see the command line arguments.  Hiding it from the log is going to have little value.

I'd suggest  encrypting the password that is stored in the MSI and have your exe capable of decrypting it.   Depending on what this password is being used for you might want to take other measures also such as having the EXE generate a random password at runtime and crypting / persisting it somewhere in case some other process needs to be able to get to it.

If the password is coming from user input in the UI sequence you could have a custom action that crypts the data as a second property then pass that to the EXE.  Or you could just fork the C++ source code to QuietExec and modify it to not write to the logfile.

Comment: No, I am not storing the password in the MSI - that would be silly. Hiding it in the log in fact has a lot of value, because the password is entered by the IT professional who then would mail the MSI log to developers (who do not know the password). I don't see why when there is already a Hidden attribute (as well as the HideTarget attribute) that users of WIX have to go to extra lengths such as encryption in order to prevent sensitive items from being logged. This looks like a bug in CAQuietExec.

Comment: The hide attribute refers to Windows Installer's msidbCustomActionTypeHideTarget attribute.  It tells the MSIEXEC engine to log the CustomActionData or not.   Once you are actually inside the deferred custom action I'm not aware of any mechanism to become aware of that flag.   There would have to be another flag that tells the QuietExec CA whether it should do anything special with regards to what it captures in the log.   Like I said, if you fork the source it can be done and since you mentioned bug in WiX... I'm sure Rob would appreciate a patch submission.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Preventing Confidential Information from Being Written into the Log File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370842.aspx) article, especially the point #3. It basically says that if a property is hidden, but Debug policy is set to a special value, the command lines will still be dumped to the log file in clear text. Verify if this can be a reason why you experience the mentioned behavior.

And I don't believe it can be a bug in QuietExec CA :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but setting the Debug policy (this is done via the registry) has no effect. I'll go along and not call this a bug in QuietExec CA - so as not to offend anybody :).

Comment: I didn't write WiX so I'm not offended, I'm just trying to be percise on what's happening here.  It's certainly a feature request to have QuietCA support filtering what gets logged.   All you can do is either patch it and rebuild WcaUtil or crypt your property and have your exe decrypt it to protect it in transit.   Do you have any other ideas on how to solve your problem?